# HTACCESS Rewrite with 2 and 3 variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have 3 variables in my URL I need on my website: page, category, and subcategory.

```
index.php?page=orders&cat=meat&sub=beef
```

Like so

My RewriteRules look like this:

**EDIT:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#Rewrite Page
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1&cat=$2&sub=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]
```

My issue is that when I try to $_GET the category, it doesn't work when there's only a category and not a subcategory

```
sitename/order/meat/beef
```

Here I can $_GET the category(meat)

```
sitename/order/meat
```

And here I can't

I'm fairly green in the htaccess department, and googling hasn't born any fruit.

What do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex makes all portions of the match mandatory rather than optional so if any are missing the entire thing fails.

Two suggested solutions,

1) replace the RewriteRule solution with

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

And then use explode() in php to get the arguments.  This is by far the most efficient solution. That is, in your php, you'd do:

```
list($page, $cat, $sub) = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/') );
```

2) Ok, let's try a different approach:

So, to update the entire ruleset:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# page
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$  index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

# page/category
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&cat=$2 [NC,L]

# page/category/sub
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&cat=$2&sub=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I tried putting that in the htaccess file, and nothing changed. I'll post an edit of original post to show full htaccess file, can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: I offered two solutions. What did you put in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't specify. I put the ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?/?$ in the htaccess file, as shown in the edit. I couldn't work out the first thing you wrote.

Comment: If you use the first solution (ie, delete all the rewrite* lines in your .htaccess and replace with that one FallbackResource line, then in your index.php file you'd do:

($page, $cat, $sub) = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/') );

Comment: Added your Rewrite and it works now, broke the css but I should be able to fix that. Thanks a bunch mate 10/10